# Getting multiple keys' values from JSON with PHP

Tags: php, json

I am trying to extract team names, players name from this json. but get no resul.

My json file looks like. any idea where I am wrong ?

```
{"items":[
{"_id":305501,"id":"305501","created_at":"2015-10-19T19:57:02+13:00","updated_at":"2015-10-19T21:34:50+13:00","name":"Match in progress","verification_level":0,
    "club_one":{"name":"Degree Club","id":14748,
        "team":{"name":"Degree College XI","id":13009,"avatar":"/original/team/default_thumb.png",
            "players":[
            {"id":null,"name":"D Vinaya"},
            {"id":617744,"name":"V Avika"},
            {"id":617745,"name":"C Rumes"},                         
            {"id":1360372,"name":"R Ferdo"}
            ],
            "innings":[{"overs":34,"over_balls":0,"runs":99,"wickets":7}]
        }
    },
    "club_two":{"name":"George Club","id":147736,
        "team":{"name":"George College XI","id":154503,"avatar":"/original/team/default_thumb.png",
            "players":[
            {"id":null,"name":"M Premathe†"},
            {"id":null,"name":"S Tion"},
            {"id":null,"name":"N Perra"},               
            {"id":1400317,"name":"S Ren"}
            ],
            "innings":[]
        }
    },
"processed":true,"visible":true,"match_level":{"name":null,"id":null}   
}   
],
"meta":{"total_pages":1}
}
```

and here is the php code.

```
$json_file = json_decode($load_json);
           foreach ($items as $item) {                
               echo $item->$json_file->_id;
                echo $item->$json_file->club_one;
                echo $item->$json_file->club_two;
                   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing it wrong. As far as your json is concerned, loop it like this

```
$json_file = json_decode($json);
foreach ($json_file->items as $item) {                
    echo $item->id;
    echo $item->club_one->name;
    echo $item->club_two->name;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. I will check it later. How about getting team name of each club ?  `echo $item->club_two->team;` will work ?

Comment: I don't know, probably for the level of the question asked. BTW as far as your question is concerned `echo $item->club_two->team;` so if your team is an array you can access it like `echo $item->club_two['team'];` or if it an object then the way you did already.

Comment: If my answer helped you, don't forget to up-vote accept the answer so other can benefit from the situation question.